# How to map multiple records from a single SP with Dapper-dot-net

Tags: c#, dapper

I'd like to use Dapper in a situation where the execution of a single stored procedure will return 50 multiple separate selects, none of the individual result sets will be very wide, maybe 20 or 30 columns at most. The code below is from the Dapper Tests and I'm wondering if this example is a good prototype to use.

Thank you,
Stephen

```
public void TestMultiMap()
        {
            var createSql = @"
                create table #Users (Id int, Name varchar(20))
                create table #Posts (Id int, OwnerId int, Content varchar(20))

                insert #Users values(99, 'Sam')
                insert #Users values(2, 'I am')

                insert #Posts values(1, 99, 'Sams Post1')
                insert #Posts values(2, 99, 'Sams Post2')
                insert #Posts values(3, null, 'no ones post')";

                connection.Execute(createSql);

            var sql = @"select * from #Posts p 
                      left join #Users u on u.Id = p.OwnerId 
                      Order by p.Id";

            var data = connection.Query<Post, User, Post>(sql, (post, user) => { post.Owner = user; return post; }).ToList();
            var p = data.First();

            p.Content.IsEqualTo("Sams Post1");
            p.Id.IsEqualTo(1);
            p.Owner.Name.IsEqualTo("Sam");
            p.Owner.Id.IsEqualTo(99);

            data[2].Owner.IsNull();

           connection.Execute("drop table #Users drop table #Posts");
    }
```

EDIT

Here is a sample based on Marcs answer.

```
        const string sql = @"__sp_GetMISMOLoanInfo";
        using (var multi = _connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new { loannum = "3192381" }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
        {
           var address = multi.Read<ADDRESS>().Single();
           var amortizationRule = multi.Read<AMORTIZATION_RULE>().Single();
           var appraiserLicense = multi.Read<APPRAISER_LICENSE>().Single();
           var automatedUnderwriting = multi.Read<AUTOMATED_UNDERWRITING>().Single();
           var avm = multi.Read<AVM>().Single();
           var borrowerDetail = multi.Read<BORROWER_DETAIL>().Single();
        }
```

Comment: Where's the SP? In particular, is it a *wide* result, or multiple separate selects? Both work with dapper, but the syntax is different between the two layouts

Comment: (I know it was just an example, but a table variable might have been better in that, btw)

Comment: Marc, I've edited the post to reflect your questions.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/835519/Passing-Table-Valued-Parameters-with-Dapper for a wrapper that simplifies the task

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This one is from the home page, but there should be similar in the tests:

```
var sql = @"...";
using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {id=selectedId}))
{
   var customer = multi.Read<Customer>().Single();
   var orders = multi.Read<Order>().ToList();
   var returns = multi.Read<Return>().ToList();
   ...
}
```

Arguments etc work as normal, and should map directly to defined parameter names if CommandType is specified.

Each call to `.Read<T>()` relates to a successive results grid.

Comment: Marc, how do I pass the paramater? Procedure or function '__sp_GetMISMOLoanInfo' expects parameter '@loannum', which was not supplied.

Comment: @SPATEN did you pass, for example, a `new {loannum = yourValue}` ?

Comment: Yes, just like the code I pasted as the EDIT. I've even set it to be a string because that is our 'Loan Number' data type. CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[__sp_GetMISMOLoanInfo]
 @loannum varchar(15)

Comment: Problem was NOT setting the CommandType as Marc had indicated. Problem solved.