# Dapper with Multiple Records from Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, ado.net, dapper

I have seen the answer to this question, [How to map multiple records from a single SP with Dapper-dot-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751052/how-to-map-multiple-records-from-a-single-sp-with-dapper-dot-net), but it doesn't seem to work for my scenario.

Dummy Tables for illustration...

I have a SP that returns multiple record sets, and the first one looks like...

```
Column1 (int), Column2 (int)
```

and I have a class...

```
public class Columns
{
    public int Column1 { get; set; }
    public int Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I am trying to build a list of columns...

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
        {
            using (var multi = conn.QueryMultiple("SpData", 
                   commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
            {
                var cols = multi.Read<Columns>().ToList();
            }
        }
```

When I call this, nothing seems to be populated in the `cols` variable, but I am not getting any errors.  Also, if I break and look at what `multi` contains, I can see the data there.  Can somebody see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether to delete the question, or just add this as an answer as I spotted the obvious error (after I woke up)

I wasn't interested in the first two datasets from the SP, so I needed to skip by using `Read`...

```
multi.Read();//skip first recordset
multi.Read();//skip second recordset
```

It might help someone else, otherwise I will delete it soon.

Comment: leave the question here IMO - it might help someone else

Comment: @MarcGravell, OK, will do.  Btw, I decided to use `Dapper` after an answer you gave me a few months back - very clean and useful, 6 lines of code v's something like 80 lines.